# Can NetBeans auto-build java free-form (Ant) projects?

Tags: netbeans, ant, netbeans6.8, freeform

After every save I need to right-click on the project in the project browser and click on `build`.
Is there a way to configure NetBeans to auto-build the project when I save a file?

Answer (score 0):

See Compile on Save FAQ:  http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqCompileOnSave

I don't use CoS myself, I highly recommend Jenkins for your auto-build needs (and so much more): http://jenkins-ci.org/

Answer (score 0):

The compile on save option is not available for free-form projects as of NetBeans version 8.0. And I don't think it will be made available in future too. The very idea of free-form is that that IDE does not know anything about your project and completely relies on the ant-scripts and the mappings you provide.

If you don't want to build an entire project every time you make changes to a file, create a target in ant to compile a single file and map it to the IDE command compile.single. You could add a context menu for that if required, although the existing keyboard shortcut F9 should suffice.

You can read more on the advance free-form configuration here - [Advanced Free-Form Project Configuration](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/freeform-config.html)